# Showing an independent sequence does not converge almost surely using Borel-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I can't seem to write a solid proof for the following problem:

Consider an independent sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables with
$$
P\left(X_n=0\right)=1-\frac{1}{n \log (n+1)}, \quad P\left(X_n=n\right)=P\left(X_n=-n\right)=\frac{1}{2 n \log (n+1)} .
$$

Show that $\frac{1}{n}\left(X_1+\cdots+X_n\right)$ does not converge almost surely.
Hint: Use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

So, from Borel-Cantelli I simply state that

$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P\left(A_n\right)= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} P(\frac{1}{2 n \log (n+1)}) < \infty$, then
$$
P\left(\limsup _{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n\right) \neq 1 
$$
and thus the seuqnece doesn ot converge a.s. I know my solution is not rigorous enough (and could be worng), so I would love to see sugestions or solutions to the problem. Thank you !

Comment: **Suggestion:** On the event $\{(X_1+\cdots + X_n)/n$ converges$\}$ you have $\lim_n X_n/n =0$. Use B.-C. to calculate $P(|X_n|/n=1$ infinitely often$)$.

Comment: Thanks ! What do you mean with infinitely often here ?

Comment: Just descriptive language for $\limsup_n\{|X_n|/n=1\}$. A sample point $\omega$ lies in $\limsup_n\{|X_n|/n=1\}$ if and only if the set $\{n: |X_n(\omega)|/n = 1\}$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n = \{|X_n|/n = 1\}$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(E_n) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n|/n=1)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\mathbb P(X_n=n)+\mathbb P(X_n=-n))\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n\log(n+1)}\\
&= +\infty,
\end{align}
so by independence of the $E_n$ the second Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that $\mathbb P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n)=1$.

Let $S_n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then it follows that
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} |S_n|>\frac12 \right) \geqslant \mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} |X_n|/n>\frac12 \right)\geqslant \mathbb P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} E_n)=1,
$$
and hence $S_n$ does not converge almost surely (to zero).

Comment: Thank you  I  arrived to (almost) the same solution by myself, but you confirmed my solution !